# What happened to the "Enable Nested Modules" option in m2-eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin

I contribute to and implement some open source projects that use a Maven2 build system organized into several sub-modules.  I've also been an Eclipse user for several years.  With these projects, I have historically leveraged the maven-eclipse plugin so that Eclipse can correctly recognise library dependencies in my project.

It used to be the case that -- when I set up a new workspace or project -- I would have to right-click select "Enable Dependency Management" followed by right-click "Enable Nested Modules."  Once I did these things, maven & eclipse would find dependent libraries properly in my .m2 local repo.

But in my most recent install of Eclipse/m2-eclipse -- Eclipse Build 20100218-1602, m2-eclipse 0.10.0.20100209-0800 (sorry, the "About" dialog doesn't provide anything better than that) -- the "Enable Nested Modules" option is missing.  Nor does the project seem willing to find my nested modules without it.

After much digging and some trial & error, I got the IDE to recognize my sub-modules by setting...

```
includeModules=true
```

In my `org.maven.ide.eclipse.pref` file manually.

But my question is:  what gives?  Why did this option disappear?  Is there some newer, better way that I should be using m2-eclipse to find nested modules?  How are other Maven & Eclipse users dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing here is the option to enable nested modules was moved to the Window >Preferences > Maven. Set the **Support multiple Maven modules mapped to single Eclipse Workspace project** checkbox, right click your project, navigate to Maven menu item you can find the 'Enable nested modules' option.

Comment: Thanks!  I know there must be someone on the planet who understood this issue.

Comment: but I cannot find this option! :(

Answer (score 4):

Looks like support for this feature was recently removed:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-2291

Answer (score 2):

> Why did this option disappear? Is there some newer, better way that I should be using m2-eclipse to find nested modules?

Could this be somehow related to the option below (accessible via **Windows > Preferences > Maven**):

[image]

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure because I don't create my projects under Eclipse, I create them on the command line outside Eclipse and import them as **Existing Maven Projects** (and this works with nested modules).

Comment: I don't create projects using eclipse either.  Normally the project already contains source, configuration, and a system of nested pom.xml files already.  I just do "New Java Project" and "from existing source."  If it's a completely "green field" project, I use archetype:create or simply hand-create a pom.xml.